# New React Hooks confused

Tags: reactjs, comparison, react-hooks

I'm new with React hooks functional component, I have some questions which need to be explained, thank you:

1. How do I can perform a deep comparison of some state before re-render? I saw that React.memo only has the 2nd argument for modify a comparison on props only, but how about the state? Currently, it uses Object.is for compare, I want to modify this function.
2. What is the principles of useCallback, useMemo? I've investigated react source code but still dont know about how can it do this. Does someone give me a simple example to illustrate how it know to cache the value on each render?

Comment: Since you asked 4 very broad questions I hope the following links will help you 
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#performance-optimizations Maybe you want to split your post into multiple questions, or show by some example how they belong together for your case.

Comment: @karfau, Thanks for your reply, I've read the post before but it does not provide the way to custom the comparison method on prevState and nextState of useState. We can only modify areEqual method of React.memo HOC but this is for compare props only

Comment: Your question #1 is about "getSnapshotBeforeUpdate" method?

Comment: @Alexandre Aragão, no, my #1 is about shouldComponentUpdate in class component that we have nextState and nextProps then we can do any comparison method to decide whether it re-render. But in functional component with hooks, I just found React.memo 2nd argument for that purpose but it can only compare props, not with the state

Comment: "getSnapshotBeforeUpdate" provides you a state comparison. But aren't implemented at ReactJS v16.8.0 version. Check [this](http://pt-br.reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html).

Comment: Thank you, so it will be the next feature release to support functional component

Comment: Hi @Alexandre Aragão, after inspect getSnapshotBeforeUpdate lifecycle, I saw it's used to provide additional value to componentDidUpdate (as 3rd argument), not for comparison to decide whether it should render

Comment: @QuocVanTang yes, but getSnapshotBeforeUpdate provides you acess to the value of previous state, then you can set the value of the state to the previous again

Comment: @Alexandre Aragão, I just want to perform a comparison between prevState and nextState, and re-render will be trigger only if the nextState is different than the prevState (different by deep compare, not shallow compare by default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1: How do I can perform a deep comparison of some state before re-render?**

In the snippet below, I show you one way of making a deep comparison of the state.

**Q2: What is the principles of useCallback, useMemo?**

`useMemo` is meant to be used in a situation where you have some expensive calculation that you want to memoize the results. So the expensive calculation only runs once for each unique combination of `inputs`.

`useCallback` is meant to avoid the re-creation of inner functions that don't need to be recreated. Unless some variable listed in the dependency array changes. It's commonly used as a performance optimization.

**As per React DOCS:**

> **useCallback**
>
> This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g. shouldComponentUpdate).

**Note:**

State changes **are meant to cause a re-render.** Why would you want to deep compare it before re-rendering? If it's changed, React MUST re-render. That's how it works.

If you want something to change and not cause a re-render, take a look at the `useRef` hook. That's exactly what it does. The `ref` object remains the same across every render (only changes if the component gets unmounted, and then re-mounted).

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

> **useRef**
>
> useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.
>
> (...)
>
> However, useRef() is useful for more than the ref attribute. It’s handy for **keeping any mutable value around similar to how you’d use instance fields in classes.**

**SNIPPET**

Comparing newState and lastState

```js
function App() {

  const [myState, setMyState] = React.useState('Initial state...');
  const lastState_Ref = React.useRef(null);
  const stateChanged_Ref = React.useRef(null);
  
  
  
  if (lastState_Ref.current !== null) {
    lastState_Ref.current === myState ?   // YOU CAN PERFORM A DEEP COMPARISON IN HERE
      stateChanged_Ref.current = false
    : stateChanged_Ref.current = true;
  }
  
  lastState_Ref.current = myState;

  function handleClick() {
    setMyState('New state...');
  }

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>myState: {myState}</div>
      <div>New state is different from last render: {JSON.stringify(stateChanged_Ref.current)}</div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

**UPDATE:**

From your comment, what you could do regarding `props` is to use `React.memo`. It will do a shallow compare on your props. See snippet below. You'll see that the regular `Child` will re-render every time and the `ChildMemo`, which is wrapped in `React.memo` won't re-render if the array `propA` remains the same.

> **React.memo**
>
> React.memo is a higher order component. It’s similar to React.PureComponent but for function components instead of classes.
>
> If your function component renders the same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost in some cases by memoizing the result. This means that React will skip rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.
>
> By default it will only shallowly compare complex objects in the props object. If you want control over the comparison, **you can also provide a custom comparison function as the second argument.**

That's what React DOCs recommend for that case:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate

```js
function App() {
  console.log('Rendering App...');
  
  const [myState,setMyState] = React.useState([1,2,3]);
  const [myBoolean,setMyBoolean] = React.useState(false);
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={()=>setMyBoolean((prevState) => !prevState)}>Force Update</button>
      <Child
        propA={myState}
      />
      <ChildMemo
        propA={myState}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Child() {
  console.log('Rendering Child...');
  
  return(
    <div>I am Child</div>
  );
}

const ChildMemo = React.memo(() => {
  console.log('Rendering ChildMemo...');
  return(
    <div>I am ChildMemo</div>
  );
});

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Regarding state, I don't think you should try to accomplish that. It should re-render if the state has changed. Actually React won't re-render if the state reference (of an object, or array) remains the same. So, if you don't change the `state` reference (like re-creating from scratch the same array or object), you already have that behavior out of the box. You can see that on the snippet below:

```js
function App() {
  console.log('Rendering App..');
  const [myArrayState,setMyArrayState] = React.useState([1,2,3]);
  
  function forceUpdate() {
    setMyArrayState((prevState) => {
      console.log('I am trying to set the exact same state array');
      return prevState;                     // Returning the exact same array
    });
  }
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>My state is: {JSON.stringify(myArrayState)}</div>
      <button onClick={forceUpdate}>Reset State(see that I wont re-render)</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Hi @cbdev420, thanks for your details explanation. For Q1, what I want is prevent re-render on state change with the newState is equal with prevState (from deep comparison). For example, prevState is the object { xyz: 1} and the newState is the new object with the same value { xyz: 1}. It like in Class component has shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle where you can perform any custom compare then return condition to re-render.

Comment: @QuocVanTang I've added some more examples and explanations. See if that helps!

Comment: Well details. And maybe another reason that when using useState hook, we also break down the state into separated smaller state (not combined to a big state object like Class component). So it's obvious to control the state change

Answer (score 2):

To add to what **cbdev420** said, here is a link to a cheatsheet which explains pretty well how to use most of the hooks, if it can help you https://react-hooks-cheatsheet.surge.sh/